# Como gerar várias estruturas de repetição aninhadas com métodos

Tags: java, for, método

preciso gerar varias estruturas aninhadas (26) queria saber como fazer isso com metodos pro codigo não ficar muito grande
um exemplo da estrutura que eu preciso com 4 aninhadas:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] vet={"1","2","3","4"};
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++) if(i!=j)
            for(int k=0;k<4;k++) if(j!=k && i!=k)
                for(int l=0;l<4;l++) if(k!=l && i!=l && j!=l)
                    System.out.println(vet[i]+vet[j]+vet[k]+vet[l]);

}
```

Comment: Por curiosidade, qual sua necessidade para precisar de 26 `for` aninhados?

Comment: Tambem gostaria de saber o que faz necessario ter 26 laços, com certeza deve ter formas melhores de fazer isso.

Comment: Apenas para reforçar o que já foi dito 26 estruturas aninhadas não é solução para nenhum problema. Repense no problema, e siga por um caminho viável, que não esse.